# React web Hover and Show modal

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tabs, frontend

I am new for web development and I was wondering if you guys could direct me to the appropriate keywords I should use to make the following possible. So, there is a website where at the top of the page, there are list of Tabs( or keywords aligned horizontally) and if I hover around one of the keywords or tabs, something like a modal comes up(like slides down), which has another list of clickable words and when the cursor is no longer hovering around the tabs, the modal just disappears.

I have prepared a gif to show the details as my wording might be very confusing. So I was wondering if you could help me how to get started with to make the same website using ReactJs. Thank you for your help in advance.

[The descriptive gif for the above problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de9Fs.gif)

Answer (score 2):

What you suggested can be achieved with simple CSS.
React will only be the tool for the rendering part.

Hopefully this snippet explains how simple the structure can be for you to achieve something similar to what you posted.

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar:hover > .navbar-dropdown {
  max-height: 200px;
}

.navbar-header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.navbar-header p {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

.navbar-dropdown {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <p>item 1</p>
      <p>item 2</p>
      <p>item 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>sub-item 1</li>
        <li>sub-item 2</li>
        <li>sub-item 3</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>sub-item 1</li>
        <li>sub-item 2</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>sub-item 1</li>
        <li>sub-item 2</li>
        <li>sub-item 3</li>
        <li>sub-item 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```